# I want help how to take text from response of http json here the source of request

Tags: c#

I want help how to take text from response of http here the source of request

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://xxxx.com/");

        var postData = "{"+'"'+"get"+ '"' +":100}";
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        request.Method = "PUT";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers["X"] = "83ed3926";


        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }



        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

now i want source code to can search in : responseString

Example:

```
{"auctionInfo":[{"IDEF":224454585435,"itemData":2 ","buyNowPrice":100,"
,{"IDEF":224454839937,"itemData":","buyNowPrice":200,"{"IDEF":315779793672,"timestamp":1539055787,"formation":"f352","Price":100,"assetrd":1,"rating":","buyNowPrice":300,"
```

I want way to take the first IDEF and buynowprice and to add them to two strings.

Example if will run the code will be:

```
IDEF = 224454839937

buyNowPrice = 100
```

To take only the first the other just skips.

Comment: Please please please: `var postData = "{\"get\":100}";`

Comment: is the post and the resopne will be in json like in up

Comment: Also, take a look into json.net, it's by far the easiest way to parse JSON structures.

Comment: can write for me full sourse becuase im new with c#

Comment: if you are receiving JSON then use newtonsoft excellent JSON.net https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: @Masad If you want that, you probably should hire a programmer. This site is for help, not for doing everything for you.

Comment: You need to write your own code - that how you learn

Answer (score 0):

As you can see your data have some structure inside that `json string` and that is object like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public int IDEF { get; set; }
    public int itemData { get; set; }
    public float buyNowPrice { get; set; }
}
```

So this is c class that is representing structure inside that json string.
Only thing left is to `Deserialize` that json string and you will do it like this:

```
List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(yourJsonStringHere);
```

And there you have it, list full of objects of class `Item`.

Comment: also this wont work as the array is not the top level item in the given sample

Comment: i have this error after i put this line
List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(yourJsonStringHere);

CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'WindowsFormsApp4.Form1.Item' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WindowsFormsApp4.Form1.Item>' WindowsFormsApp4

Comment: var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(responseString);

Comment: @Masad missed one thing. I defined to deserialize object as `Item` not `List<Item>` edited it now

Comment: still have this error
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WindowsFormsApp4.Form1+Item]'.'

Answer (score 0):

The first problem here is that your [JSON](https://www.json.org) (the text) is broken...

It should look like this:

```
{
  "auctionInfo": [
    {
      "IDEF": 224454585435,
      "itemData": 2,
      "buyNowPrice": 100
    },
    {
      "IDEF": 224454839937,
      "itemData": 0,
      "buyNowPrice": 200
    },
    {
      "IDEF": 315779793672,
      "timestamp": 1539055787,
      "formation": "f352",
      "Price": 100,
      "assetrd": 1,
      "rating": 0,
      "buyNowPrice": 300
    }
  ]
}
```

You can explore that JSON above at [this site](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu).

Now that the JSON is in the correct format, you can parse it using a Nuget package called NewtonSoft JSON:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = "{\"auctionInfo\":[{\"IDEF\":224454585435,\"itemData\":2,\"buyNowPrice\":100},{\"IDEF\":224454839937,\"itemData\":0,\"buyNowPrice\":200},{\"IDEF\":315779793672,\"timestamp\":1539055787,\"formation\":\"f352\",\"Price\":100,\"assetrd\":1,\"rating\":0,\"buyNowPrice\":300}]}";
        dynamic theObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
        dynamic auctionInfo = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray)theObject.auctionInfo;
        var theFirstItem = auctionInfo[0];
        var idef = theFirstItem.IDEF;
        var price = theFirstItem.buyNowPrice;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("IDEF: {0}, Price: {1}",idef,price));
    }
}
```

The first part of the JSON is an object (this is why we parse to a `JObject`), but it contains an array called "auctionInfo". We must therefore cast `theObject.auctionInfo` to a `JArray`. Finally, you want the first item from array and so we take the item at the 0 index...

The item at index 0 has what you want (the IDEF and the price), and so we then print them to the console.

You can see this code and run it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ivNMb6).

Comment: but the string of jjson is will be respone of request i dont know it so i can do

        var json = responseString; ??

Comment: i have this error 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'auctionInfo' because the respone is come from post

String IDFE = ID; Number of id
String Price = Price number

and i want to make string in systeam like

Comment: this error still come

Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'auctionInfo''

Comment: @Masad The JSON you supplied in your question is not formatted correctly. I mentioned that in my answer. I gave you a full working solution providing the JSON `responseString` is in the correct format. If you are getting the error you say, then there is no `auctionInfo` array... Give us the URL where the JSON comes from, or fix your question...